# AjaxControlToolkit HtmlEditor Pasting gives error, e is undefined

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I give up...Need some help please...

I have an AjaxControlToolkit HtmlEditor.  It was working and now it is not.  It may be from a recent updated but not positive.  I have tried the latest version of the tool kit and get the same error.  I does look like my web config change, because my sanitizes were missing.  After adding those back I still get the same error.  Pretty sure I followed directions correctly but not sure.

"**e is undefined**" when I paste using the buttons on the toolbar.

created and empty solution and added it there with just the basics and still get the same error.

I have googled and googled this but I don't see any solution.

I have checked over these sites to ensure I has doing every thing correctly...
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Control-Toolkit-HtmlEditorExtender-Sanitizer-provider-is-not-configured-in-the-WebConfig-file.aspx

https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Upgrade%20your%20project%20to%20AjaxControlToolkit%20v15.1

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs

screen shot of error as requested.  It gets thrown on __toStringFormat in the MS js.

e = arguments[0]

[image: error screen shot]

in addition I have tried the HtmlEditorExtender and seems to work in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox, get the same error.

Comment: So this control works, but gives an error in browser's console when you paste a text using the button? Could you provide a screenshot of that error?

Comment: Yes Mikhail, you are correct.  I had a couple other developers try and they get the same error.

Comment: There seem to be a kind of bug inside the extender, but it's hard to say what is wrong without debugging. Would you please post an [issue here](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues) so we can mark this as official bug and guarantee support for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mikhail.  See the answer below to see.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to say its a bug...

Finding out that the `document.execCommand('paste')` still does not work for Chrome or Firefox.  Security reasons.  Whereas IE says the heck with security.  The asp ajax extender makes a call to this and returns the result.  If there is a bug then its how they handle this error.  Probably should just have shown an alert letting the user know they it will not work in there browser.  I will point this out to the ajax team.

All the editors I can find have you press ctrl+v. Some for chrome have you download and extension from the google store. Not sure the point of having a paste button at all in the editors if it does not work.